# Некорректный URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Имеется простейшее Spring MVC приложение. При переходе с first-view.jsp на ask-emp-details-view.jsp и с ask-emp-details-view.jsp на show-emp-details-view.jsp Tomcat выдает ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Я так понял неправильно прописывается URL. Но в чём причина и как её исправить?

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="ru.badziy.spring.mvc" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

 <display-name>spring-course-mvc</display-name>

 <absolute-ordering />

 <servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

MyController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showFirstView() {
        return "first-view";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/askDetails")
    public String askEmployeeDetails() {
        return "ask-emp-details-view";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showDetails")
    public String showEmpDetails(@RequestParam("employeeName") String empName, Model model) {
        empName = "Mr. " + empName + "!";
        model.addAttribute("nameAttribute", empName);
        return "show-emp-details-view";
    }
}
```

first-view.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h2>I wish you luck in Spring MVC learning!!!</h2>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<a href="/askDetails">Please write your details</a>

</body>

</html>
```

ask-emp-details-view.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h2>Dear employee, Please enter you details</h2>

<br>
<br>

<form action="/showDetails" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="employeeName"
    placeholder="Write your name"/>

    <input type="submit"/>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

show-emp-details-view.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h2>Dear employee, you are WELCOME!!!</h2>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!--Your name: ${param.employeeName}-->
Your name: ${nameAttribute}

</body>

</html>
```

[Github репозиторий проекта](https://github.com/badziy/ru.badziy.spring.mvc.git)

Comment: `При переходе между view Tomcat выдает ошибку:` при переходе откуда куда? на какой конкретно странице?

Comment: @МихаилРебров При переходе с first-view.jsp на ask-emp-details-view.jsp и с ask-emp-details-view.jsp на show-emp-details-view.jsp .

Comment: @badziy Покажи git с этим проектом. А то получается гадание на не кофейной гуще. :)

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh  https://github.com/badziy/ru.badziy.spring.mvc.git

Comment: @badziy Скажи, а вот эта аннотация `@RequestMapping("/employee")` в MyController она у тебя что делает?

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh RequestMapping указывает, что все методы в данном Контроллере относятся к URL-адресу "/employee".

Comment: @badziy Не нужна это аннотация там. Из-за нее ты получаешь 404. По этому урлу ничего не находит и кидает 404 not found.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Без этой аннотации та же самая ошибка 404 при переходе между view.

Comment: @badziy В мавен сделай clean, а затем package. И стартуй приложение.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Та же ошибка. У меня начальный URL выглядит так: http://localhost:8080/ru_badziy_spring_mvc/  (first-view) при переходе на (ask-emp-details-view ) URL становится таким:  http://localhost:8080/askDetails хотя в Run Configurations прописано, что URL должен начинаться на http://localhost:8080/ru_badziy_spring_mvc/

Comment: @badziy В настройках tomcat убери этот урл (ru_badziy_spring_mvc), чтобы был просто /
У тебя сейчас в томкат такой урл /ru_badziy_spring_mvc

Comment: @badziy Зайди в томкат (edit configuration), затем Deployment и в Application context: укажи / затем Apply и OK

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Спасибо за советы. Там оказывается в view в ссылках надо было без слешей писать: showDetails и askDetails . Заработало.

Comment: @badziy Во вьюхах все правильно написано. В томкате не нужно в Application context никаких ru_badziy_spring_mvc, кроме слеша.